# Scrapy Crawlspider is only crawling the first 5 pages in a category

Tags: scrapy

Currently, my crawlspider will only crawl roughly 20,000 products of the over 6.5M available. It seems that each category is being scraped but only the first 5 pages of each category are being scraped. I believe that is is something with my linkextractor but I am not sure.

CrawlSpider:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

from scrapy.selector import Selector

class DigikeyItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    partnumber = scrapy.Field()
    manufacturer = scrapy.Field()
    description = scrapy.Field()
    quanity= scrapy.Field()
    minimumquanity = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()

class DigikeySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'digikey'
    allowed_domains = ['digikey.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.digikey.com/products/en']

    rules = (

        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('products', )),callback='parse_item'),

    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        for row in response.css('table#productTable tbody tr'):
            item = DigikeyItem()
            item['partnumber'] = row.css('.tr-mfgPartNumber [itemprop="name"]::text').extract_first()
            item['manufacturer'] =  row.css('[itemprop="manufacture"] [itemprop="name"]::text').extract_first()
            item['description'] = row.css('.tr-description::text').extract_first()
            item['quanity'] = row.css('.tr-qtyAvailable::text').extract_first()
            item['price'] = row.css('.tr-unitPrice::text').extract_first()
            item['minimumquanity'] = row.css('.tr-minQty::text').extract_first()
            yield item
```

Setting:

```
BOT_NAME = 'digikey'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['digikey.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'digikey.spiders'



ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
}
```

Output:

```
2017-11-01 10:53:11 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-11-01 10:53:11 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 6,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived': 6,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 1198612,
 'downloader/request_count': 988,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 988,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 23932614,
 'downloader/response_count': 982,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 982,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 46,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 1, 17, 53, 11, 421641),
 'item_scraped_count': 21783,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 22773,
 'log_count/ERROR': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 982,
 'retry/count': 4,
 'retry/max_reached': 2,
 'retry/reason_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived': 4,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 988,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 988,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 988,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 988,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 1, 17, 49, 38, 427669)}
2017-11-01 10:53:11 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
PS C:\Users\dalla_000\digikey>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this particular site, it might make sense to do a two-stage crawl:

1. get a list of all the category URLs
2. iterate over all the URLs

One approach could be to use two spiders and a message queue. The first spider might look like this:

```
import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import math
import urllib
from kafka import KafkaClient, SimpleProducer

ITEMS_PER_PAGE = 500

class CreateXxxxxxxUrlListSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    kafka = KafkaClient('10.0.1.12:9092')
    producer = SimpleProducer(kafka)

    name = "create_xxxxxxx_url_list"
    allowed_domains = ["xxxxxxx.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.xxxxxxx.com/product-search/en?stock=1"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body)

        catfilterlinks = soup.find_all('a', {'class':'catfilterlink'})

        for catfilterlink in catfilterlinks:
            location = catfilterlink['href'].split("?")[0]
            items = re.match(".*\(([0-9]+) items\).*", catfilterlink.next_sibling).group(1)

            for page in range(int(math.ceil(float(items) / ITEMS_PER_PAGE))):
                if page == 0:
                    url = "http://www.xxxxxxx.com" + location + "?" + urllib.urlencode({"stock":1})
                    self.producer.send_messages("xxxxxxx_search_page_urls", url)
                else:
                    url = "http://www.xxxxxxx.com" + location + "/page/" + str(page + 1) + "?" + urllib.urlencode({"stock":1})
                    self.producer.send_messages("xxxxxxx_search_page_urls", url)
```

The first spider gets a list of all the pages to crawl and then writes them to a message queue (e.g. Kafka).

The second spider would consume URLs from from the Kafka topic and crawl them. It might look something like this:

```
from scrapy_kafka.spiders import ListeningKafkaSpider
from .. items import PageHtml
from calendar import timegm
import time

class CrawlXxxxxxxUrlsSpider(ListeningKafkaSpider):
    name = 'crawl_xxxxxxx_urls_spider'
    allowed_domains = ["xxxxxxx.com"]
    topic = "xxxxxxx_search_page_urls"

    def parse(self, response):
        item = PageHtml()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['html'] = response.body_as_unicode()
        item['ts'] = timegm(time.gmtime())
        return item
        # .... or whatever
```